# Restricting accesses on views based on the custom user type in Django

Tags: python, django, django-custom-user

I created a custom user using AbstractUser with 3 user types

```
    USER_TYPE = (
    ("type1", "type1"),
    ("type2", "type2"),
    ("type3", "type3"),
)

class User(AbstractUser):
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=USER_TYPE, null=True, blank=True, default="")
```

and each user have a dashboard its only visible to the corresponding user, but my case I can access all dashboard if any user is logged in so how to restrict the access based on this user types (type1, type2, type3 ) I am using class-based views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) mixin

```
class YourView(UserPassesTestMixin, View):

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.user_type == 'type1'
```

Comment: Does it just return the current user type right? I need to make a view only accessible by type1 user

Comment: Adding this to your view would only allow users where `user_type == 'type1' ` to access the view. So long as `request.user` is your custom user model

Comment: handle_no_permission
    raise PermissionDenied(self.get_permission_denied_message())
django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied
 page shows a 403  Forbidden

Comment: Is the user you are logged in as "type1"?